# HTML table in PHP

Tags: php, sql, html-table

I have the following code but it's not working like I want it to work. I just want the table header to be shown once but now it repeats the header everytime. And I want the table header to be horizontally but now it is vertically.

code:

```
<?php
include ("core/db_connectie.php");

//file_get_contents("main.tpl.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM platen";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

$table = "<table>"; 

$cName = "";
$cValue = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
    foreach($row as $columnName=>$columnValue)
    {
        $cName .= $columnName;
        $cValue .= $columnValue; 
    }
}

$table .= "<tr><th>". $cName ."</th></tr>"; 
$table .= "<tr><td>". $cValue ."</td></tr>"; 

$table .= "</table>"; 

echo $table;
```

**EDIT:**

I changed the code but it's still not working now it just paste everything after eachother

Example:

```
IDAlbumBandStijlMediumDatumPrijsIDAlbumBandStijlMediumDatumPrijs
1TestTestereRockLP2013-06-1202TestTestereRockLP2013-06-1213
```

Comment: $table .= "<tr><th>" . $columnName . "</th></tr>"; is in the loop. You should put it outside

Comment: Ye but if I do that I can't use $columName anymore

Comment: Sure. You had to get column names first if you want to put them once before the loop

Comment: Other way is to have table with two columns

Answer (score 0):

You have placed the table header tag inside foreach loop. place it out and it will be ok.

$table .= "" . $columnName . "";(place this out of foreach loop)

Comment: This way he hadn't the column name

Comment: I can't place $columnName out of the foreach loop because I define it in the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to put the code which render the headers outside the loop, otherwise it will be repetead at each iteration. I don't know which format your data have, a simple solution would be to use two loop, although I'm sure you can find a better way:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
    foreach($row as $columnName=>$columnValue)
    {
        $table .= "<tr><th>" . $columnName . "</th></tr>";
    }
    foreach($row as $columnName=>$columnValue)
    {
        $table .= "<tr><td>" . $columnValue . "</td></tr>";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want the header in the first row, so you have to remember if you have written the header yet:

```
<?php
include ("core/db_connectie.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM platen";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$table = "<table>"; 

$headerWritten = false;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
    foreach($row as $columnName=>$columnValue)
    {
        if(!$headerWritten) {
            $table .= "<tr><th>" . $columnName . "</th></tr>";
        }
        $table .= "<tr><td>" . $columnValue . "</td></tr>";  
    }
    $headerWritten = true;
}

$table .= "</table>"; 

echo $table;
?>
```

This is the simplest way to do this.

Comment: add $headerWritten = true in the if statement. Elsewhere it will newer became true

Comment: If I try this it only outputs 1 header-item

Comment: The $headerWritten = true; had to be at the end of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

```
    foreach($row as $columnName=>$columnValue)
    {
        $table .= "<tr><th>" . $columnName . "</th>";
        $table .= "<td>" . $columnValue . "</td></tr>";  
    }
```

}

Bruce
https://www.facebook.com/blanct.timeline?ref=br_tf